# how to store sql query result in a variable and messegeBox

Tags: sql, ssis

[image]

I have a simple sql query in my Execute sql task in ssis package,
SELECT        MAX(binindex)
FROM            dbo.myTable

I need to store this maximum index into a variable and then pass it to  Script Task and display it,
I already declared a package variable, the package compiles, however it shows -1 every time, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help will be appreciated!

[image]

```
public void Main(){
    //TODO: Add your code here
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::BININDEX"].Value.ToString());
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the column binindex in dbo.MyTable? What is the data type of the SSIS variable @[User::BININDEX]?

Comment: Do you get the same result when you run the query in SSMS (I assume not else you wouldn't be asking the question)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Parameter Mapping page?

Comment: the parameter Mapping Page is blank!! I dont have anything

Comment: Sorry, I meant the General Tab. Not enough tea this afternoon. Curious about the connection manager type and the resultset property

Comment: Hopefully the last comment/question before I can provide an answer. In your variables window, is the value of @[User::BININDEX] set to -1 right now (at design time)?

Comment: No...............I just uploaded the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news, is that you are doing everything correctly as far as I can see. I recreated your package and I get the expected value from my query.

[image: Basic package]

I can also induce your situation - the correct value is returned from my query but my package produces an "incorrect result."

[image: negative one]

The problem, I hope, is that you have two BININDEX variables defined at different scopes. My original assumption was the Package scoped one contained a value of -1 and you had a variable scoped to the "Execute SQL Task" with the same name. The default behaviour is a variable is created scoped to the object that currently has focus. This changes in the 2012 release of SQL Server by the way.

As your picture shows a design-time value of 123 for the package scoped variable, the possibility also exists that you have a variable defined on the Script Task with the same name of BININDEX. The local variable would override the globally scoped variable

[image: variables window]

Click on your Script Task and hopefully you'll see a BININDEX defined there like the above. Otherwise, I think the problem is somewhere in your package, you have conflicting BININDEX variables. You can try slogging through the Package Explorer looking for an instance where you have two variables with the same name listed.

[image: package explorer]

I need to leave but if none of that is the case, add a PostExecute breakpoint on the Execute SQL Task and look at your Locals window (not Variables as that only reflects Design-time values). Expand Variables and you should be able to see the value of BININDEX. Is it correct there?

[image]